# Infinite empty space next to the last slide on the 'Swiper Slide' (it disappears when the window size is changed)

Tags: jquery, css, swiper.js

There is a problem with the swipe slide.
Images of various horizontal sizes are used on this slide, and the total horizontal length is set to 'auto'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var swiper = new Swiper(".note-container", {
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  spaceBetween: 0,
  freeMode: true,
  observer: true, 
  observeParents: true,
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
    onlyInViewport: false,
  },
});
```

Now, even after the last slide, there is still an empty space.
If there's no problem, it has to end without empty space on the last slide.
But if I change the size of the window a little, the problem of unlimited horizontal slides with the empty space at the end of the slide disappears.
There is a problem only when I access the first page.

Also, if I delete the 'lazy loading', the problem disappears.